# expected a single-segment buffer object using sio.savemat

Tags: python, matlab, file-io, numpy, scipy

I am using `sio.savemat` to save a dictionary into a .mat. I have the following code with result being an numpy array of size `(209374,8)` and Type `string96`:

```
import scipy.io as sio

column=['some','numbers','12oh','and','some','pure','caracter','strings']

final = { column[0] : result[:,0]}
for i in range(1,np.size(column)):
    final[column[i]]= result[:,i]

sio.savemat('/some/directory/name.mat', final)
```

After running I get following error message and I cannot determine how to solve:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/florian/Documents/eval/python/ofr.py", line 88, in <module>
    sio.savemat('/home/florian/Documents/eval/tiwa/mat/ofr.mat', final)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 204, in savemat
    MW.put_variables(mdict)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 872, in put_variables
    self._matrix_writer.write_top(var, asbytes(name), is_global)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 622, in write_top
self.write(arr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 657, in write
self.write_char(narr, codec)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py", line 707, in     write_char
arr = arr_to_chars(arr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py", line 402, in arr_to_chars
buffer=arr)
TypeError: expected a single-segment buffer object
```

Specifications of my system:

- Kubuntu 14.04
- Spyder 2.2.5
- Python 2.7.6
- numpy 1.8.1
- Scipy 0.13.3

Since I have no idea where that comes from thanks for any help or hint.

Comment: the key `'some'` will be overwritten to the last entry in the dictionary `finel`